# HSV colour space and CvInRangeS function

Tags: opencv, hsv

```
cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(15, 234, 120), cvScalar(21, 234, 120), imgThreshed);
```

I am wondering what each parameter in the cvScalar function represents. I thought it  would be HSV but it doesnt seem to be thresholding the desired color. Could someone explain the parameters a bit clearer?

Comment: [This page](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/message/76742) looks like it has a good description. It looks like the first scalar is the min hsv values and the second is the max hsv values. It checks to see if all values are between the min and max.

Comment: do you know what h,s and v go up to. For example i would typically say that for rgb the values are out of 255. It seems to be different for HSv. im not sure what opencv uses

Comment: Typically hue is in the range of 0 to 360 degrees, though it's sometimes represented as 0 to 255 to make it fit within 8 bits. Saturation and Value are generally 0 to 100, but may be stretched to 0 to 255 to use the full 8-bit range, too. So I guess what I'm saying is you'll need to read the documentation on whatever you used to convert to HSV.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means

H - Hue, S - Saturation, V - Value

take a look in here for understanding each one of those:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV

the color is mainly defined in the Hue component. There is a good tutorial about thresholding in HSV space in here:

http://aishack.in/tutorials/thresholding/

Answer (score 10):

`cvInrangeS` function checks that array elements lie between two scalars.

First cvScalar value denotes inclusive lower boundary.
Second cvScalar value denotes exclusive upper boundary.

cvInrangeS doesn't care the values you give as either RGB or BGR or HSV etc. It just goes through the array elements you give as input (first parameter)(here it is an image) and checks if elements are in the given range you specified. If so, it is selected, otherwise rejected. And feed result to last parameter, your output image.

Check out its [documentation](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/operations_on_arrays.html#inranges)

Now here if you give a HSV image. So cvScalar denotes lowest and highest color of range you want to extract.

If it is RGB image, you specify min and max RGB colors.

And better use HSV because it provides good result. [Read here](http://aishack.in/tutorials/color-spaces-1/).

And now if you want to convert RGB to HSV values, Try [here](http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx) and [here.](http://www.colorblender.com/)

(Remember, in OpenCV red and blue interchanged. It is BGR, not RGB).

Comment: Updated the dead link here.